# Why does my product disappear after a while in magento 2?

Tags: magento, product, reindex, indexer

my site lost products after a few hours.

I used the command "bin/magento indexer:reindex", the product appeared. But then it disappeared again and showed the words "We can't find products matching the selection" on the category page. can anyone help me?